# How to deactivate a conda environment before the batch file exits when closing a jupyter lab instance?

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd, jupyter-lab, anaconda3

I have a batch file that I use to run my jupyter lab.

file.bat

```
call <anaconda_dir>\Scripts\activate.bat rasa_ai_conda
jupyter lab
conda deactivate
call conda.bat deactivate
```

This batch file will activate my rasa virtual environment in anaconda using the windows prompt.

So now when I press `ctrl+c` for closing my jupyter lab it asks this

```
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

First of, the prompt closes even if I enter 'N', how do I fix this.

Secondly, I want all of my script executed before the prompt exits, how do I do this?

Tried searching for fix to this issue but still not able to figure out a solution.

Comment: `jupyter lab stop <port>`?

Comment: @Gerhard I replaced the port with this ```http://localhost:<port>/lab```. But it didn't do anything, still the prompt closes. Did I do it wrong?

Comment: no. just do `jupyter list` to see the running instances and use the relevant port. i.e `jupyter lab stop 8888`

Comment: @Gerhard but the thing is how do i enter these values while my batch file is running?

Comment: I even changed it to this
```call <anaconda_dir>\Scripts\activate.bat rasa_ai_conda```
```jupyter lab```
```jupyter lab stop 8888```
```conda deactivate```
```call conda.bat deactivate```
```pause```

But it didnt help

Comment: When I did ```jupyter lab stop 8888```on a new cmd prompt it gave me this error
```Shutting down server on 8888...```
```Could not stop server on 8888```

Comment: No, you should not use port `8888`. It was an example. `jupyter list` will show your instance.. use that port.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243875/discussion-between-inderjeet-singh-yadav-and-gerhard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I finally found the fix for this. As far as I understood this is what was happening. Correct me if I am wrong.

So, it turns out that in the batch file jupyter lab is also calling its own batch file. Which replaces the cmd (current process) unlike calling an .exe file which will pause the prompt and run it as a new process. When the jupyter lab instance is closed it basically ends the process, i.e. jupyter lab process which had replaced the cmd process, in turn closing the prompt as it takes that to be the end of the process.

But when we use `call` a new process is initialized keeping the original process at pause i.e. cmd prompt paused in the background.

So, when current running process i.e. jupyter lab is closed, the control is shifted to the previous process i.e. cmd prompt, which will continue to run the next command until the end.

In the above batch file we just have to make these changes

```
call <anaconda_dir>\Scripts\activate.bat rasa_ai_conda
call jupyter lab
call conda.bat deactivate
```

This will run all the commands even after terminating jupyter lab server instance after pressing `ctrl+c`. So if we enter `n` for `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?`, the commands following jupyter lab will run as well.

This fixes both my issues.

Please let me know if I understood it correctly. If not please do give the correct explanation for what is happening.